# How do I create an intranet html page that downloads an APK file?

Tags: android, html, download, href, apk

I have a very simple html page on our local intranet, would like others to be able to click a link to download an APK file so that they can beta test on their Android devices.

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="//intranet/files/myapp.apk" >
```

If I click on the link I get:

"404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

If I right click on the link and choose "Save target as..." it opens a dialog with the file name as "myapp_apk" (replaced the "." with "_")

If I double click on the APK file in Windows Explorer it opens it as an installer, so it seems like a valid extension.

Is there some trick to get that to do a download?

Thanks.

Comment: From the same browser & machine can you download APK files from the Internet? [ http://android-wifi-tether.googlecode.com/files/wifi_tether_v3_1-pre115.apk ]

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure, but i  think you're loading that file via SMB, or file-sharing, which is fine, but not suitable for your purposes.

Since you have this page on a intranet server, you should put the APK on the same (web) server and link to it that way. this means that you should be able to write a url to access the file ( sort of like this http://my_intranet_server/my/path/to/the/file.apk )

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add the APK file extension into the MIME types found under IIS manager.